# Multiple high scores from Game Center leaderboard

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm looking to do an "arcade" style high score list on my game. That is, print the top 10 scores for a player and her friends, allowing multiple scores for a given player.

After reading several times through Apple's documentation, it seems that the filtering (take only one score per player) happens behind the scenes and is unable to be turned off. I also don't see how to obtain all scores for a given player so that I can do the filtering on my end.

### Questions:

- [please, oh please] Am I misreading the documentation? Is there actually a way to get the top 10 scores (allowing multiple entries per player) for a given `player` + `friends`?
- Is it possible to get all the scores or all the scores for a given `player`?